# Missing text on comment vote box in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I tap on a comment that I've already upvoted, it brings up the "Comment options" box like normal. But there are no selectable options. It seems like the dialog is being populated without selectable options or we're missing a string of text? And as @ShaWizDowArd points out, once you've upvoted on the main sites, the actions are removed, so maybe remove the box entirely?

[image]

Comment: In the normal site once you upvote or flag a comment, you won't see any icons when hovering anymore. Guess it should be the same in the app i.e. don't show anything when tapping.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess I haven't had enough caffeine this morning to remember that detail.... editing the post to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.68 out now. My local dev build had "Flag" as an option there which made me not see that it would be empty on non-dev builds.

Comment: Those dev-only builds will get you every time

Comment: So.... _should_ I be able to flag comments that I've already upvoted? The site disallows it, but the app doesn't.

Comment: @HodofHod Fixed in next version update, it should match the site.