# Please let us flag comments we've upvoted in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app, comment-flags

On the Android app, could we have the ability to flag comments we've previously upvoted? This is a fairly regular need for me, and I ran into it again earlier: I flag comments as obsolete when they are, and fairly often, one of them will be a comment I've upvoted.

For an example of a typical case: a comment suggests a great improvement to a question, I upvote it, the author performs that improvement, the comment is now obsolete and (on my PC) I flag it as obsolete. The comments get cleaned up and the question moves on.

There's a request that's been around since 2011 for the site itself: [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104184/152515). It's implemented by SOUP (as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216147/152515)), but the Android app doesn't have a SOUP available to add this functionality to the app for me.

Comment: [Per Kasra's comment on this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208024/missing-text-on-comment-vote-box-in-android-app#comment664963_208307), I have a feeling this is [status-bydesign] until the behavior changes on the sites without the use of SOUP.

Answer (score 6):

This was originally declined because the main site, at the time, did not allow flagging an upvoted comment.

However, [this is now implemented on the main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236522/152515): you can flag comments after upvoting them. (But you can't upvote after flagging.) This behaviour is now officially sanctioned, in other words.

In light of this change, I suggest the app should be updated to enable this behaviour.

Comment: Here's a comment for testing. Make sure your SOUP is disabled (if you have it) so you can be sure it's the main site letting you do this. Upvote this comment, then note you still have the option to flag it.

Answer (score 0):

We talked about this a bit internally, and I think this is going to be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Historically, flagging a comment used to only exist for "This comment is bad or abusive", and while the use case you supply makes perfect sense, I don't think the app should officially sanction being able to flag something after you've already voted on it. If this changes on the site at some point in the future, we'll implement it in the app too.

Comment: I don't think that feature request can logically be by design. It can be rejected, it can be planned, but not by design. No?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Touché.

Comment: Umm... the main site allow this, is there any change of position about the app?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The main site has since changed its position on this. Could you re-review? (See my answer.)

Comment: @Kasra Ping. You said *"If this changes on the site at some point in the future, we'll implement it in the app too."* - this has changed on the site, and we've been able to stably flag comments we've also upvoted for about a year now. Could you review the [status-declined] tag on this question, and whether it's still really declined?

Comment: A friendly remind: can you reconsider this?