# Add Comment or Answer on a site you're not user of - doesn't ask "Add to your sites" question

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

When I tap on an Upvote or Downvote button on a question from a site that I'm not registered on, I get this dialog in the Android app (Version <s>1.0.50</s> **1.0.51**):

[image: Add to your sites? You're not a member of Chemistry yet. Would you like to join? Cancel | Join Site]

I used to get this when I tap "Add comment". But in the recent version, I just get taken to the comment text box. I feel this could be very misleading as I could write a comment, then be greeted to join when attempting to post it.

Actually I just tried doing that, and I was not greeted to join, but simply got a red error message.

[image: The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site.]

Also for "Add an answer" I don't get this dialog (though I don't remember if I used to). Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) to allow anonymous answers? If yes, there should be an informational message on the editor page. If not, it should also show the join greeting.

**Note:** I already saw the following posts.

> [Error when commenting or answering on a site where you are not registered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213816/201738)
>   [Android app error when posting an answer on a site you have never created a user on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192295/201738)

Comment: +1. For "Add comment", I think this is a regression since 1.0.49 (see my comment on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239803/241919)). For "Add an answer", I didn't try on older version, so I couldn't confirm it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the older versions used to ask the question. This started with 1.0.50. I thought .51 was fixing it (as per the *what's new* text), but it didn't.

Comment: @Kasra Will there be any fix for this soon? I'm still ending up writing comments on sites I didn't join.

Comment: From what I know, you can only ping someone who has commented on/edited your post (your comment ping-ed me instead). The other way is to put a bounty...

Comment: Oh yeah I suppose. Why doesn't the site reject ineffective @ references then? Another issue perhaps. In any case Kasra seemed to regularly check the app bug feed, but missed this one for so long. And no reply from anyone else.

Comment: Related: [Improve “anonymous” answering workflow in Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242998/improve-anonymous-answering-workflow-in-android-app)