# Improve "anonymous" answering workflow in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login

When you attempt to answer a question while logged out in the Android app, you get an unpleasant error message:

[image: screenshot of android]

I know the desktop website allows semi-anonymous answering of questions via a name and email address. But I expected the app to give me a dialog box similar to when you attempt to ask a question when logged out forcing someone to signup or login.

Can the app ask someone to log in before allowing them to answer the question similar to the Ask A Question button? Or give them a name and email address fields so they're able to post an answer similar to the desktop site?

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Like you suggested, anonymous users will get prompted to sign up when tapping "Add an answer".